# JQGrid does not display data

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have created both client and server side for JQgrid and ASP.net. The grid is displayed but with no data. I could not see the result. The grid displayed but no data.

Server side
coding

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace sample
    {
        public struct JQGridResults
        {
            public int page;
            public int total;
            public int records;
            public JQGridRow[] rows;

        }
        public struct JQGridRow
        {
            public int id;
            public string[] cell;
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class User
        {
            public int UserID
            { get; set; }

            public string UserName
            { get; set; }

            public string FirstName
            { get; set; }

            public string MiddleName
            { get; set; }

            public string LastName
            { get; set; }

            public string EmailID
            { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Summary description for jqgridhandler
            /// </summary>
            public class jqGridHandler : IHttpHandler
            {

                public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
                {
                    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                    HttpResponse response = context.Response;

                    string _search = request["_search"];
                    string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
                    string pageIndex = request["page"];
                    string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
                    string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];


                    int totalRecords;
                    Collection<User> users = GetUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
                    string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
                    response.Write(output);
                }

                private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords)
                {

                    JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
                    List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
                    foreach (User user in users)
                    {
                        JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
                        row.id = user.UserID;
                        row.cell = new string[6];
                        row.cell[0] = user.UserID.ToString();
                        row.cell[1] = user.UserName;
                        row.cell[2] = user.FirstName;
                        row.cell[3] = user.MiddleName;
                        row.cell[4] = user.LastName;
                        row.cell[5] = user.EmailID;
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    result.rows = rows.ToArray();
                    result.page = pageIndex;
                    result.total = totalRecords / numberOfRows;
                    result.records = totalRecords;
                    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
                }

                private Collection<User> GetUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords)
                {
                    Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
                    string connectionString = "";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            command.Connection = connection;
                            command.CommandText = "select * from tblusers" ; 
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // StoredProcedure;

                            SqlParameter paramPageIndex = new SqlParameter("@PageIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
                            paramPageIndex.Value = Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex);
                            command.Parameters.Add(paramPageIndex);

                            SqlParameter paramColumnName = new SqlParameter("@SortColumnName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                            paramColumnName.Value = sortColumnName;
                            command.Parameters.Add(paramColumnName);

                            SqlParameter paramSortorderBy = new SqlParameter("@SortOrderBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
                            paramSortorderBy.Value = sortOrderBy;
                            command.Parameters.Add(paramSortorderBy);

                            SqlParameter paramNumberOfRows = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfRows", SqlDbType.Int);
                            paramNumberOfRows.Value = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows);
                            command.Parameters.Add(paramNumberOfRows);

                            SqlParameter paramTotalRecords = new SqlParameter("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.Int);
                            totalRecords = 0;
                            paramTotalRecords.Value = totalRecords;
                            paramTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            command.Parameters.Add(paramTotalRecords);


                            connection.Open();

                            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                User user;
                                while (dataReader.Read())
                                {
                                    user = new User();
                                    user.UserID = (int)dataReader["UserID"];
                                    user.UserName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["UserName"]);
                                    user.FirstName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FirstName"]);
                                    user.MiddleName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["MiddleName"]);
                                    user.LastName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["LastName"]);
                                    user.EmailID = Convert.ToString(dataReader["EmailID"]);
                                    users.Add(user);
                                }
                            }
                            totalRecords = (int)paramTotalRecords.Value;
                        }

                        return users;
                    }

                }
                public bool IsReusable
                {
                    // To enable pooling, return true here.
                    // This keeps the handler in memory.
                    get { return false; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Client side

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<!-- The jQuery UI theme that will be used by the grid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!-- The jQuery UI theme extension jqGrid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <!-- jQuery runtime minified -->
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- The localization file we need, English in this case -->
    <script src="js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- The jqGrid client-side javascript -->
    <script src="js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 250,
                colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'MiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'EmailID', width: 150, sortable: true }
                    ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#UsersGridPager',
                sortname: 'UserID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                caption: 'JSON Example'
            });

            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%--<form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">--%>
    <table id="UsersGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <div id="UsersGridPager"></div>

   <%-- </form>--%>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with it? Data is not displayed.
Thank you

Updated

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "jqGridHandler.ashx",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                var JQResult = JSON.parse(result);

                colD = JQResult.colData;
                colN = JQResult.colNames;
                var colM = JQResult.colModel;

                alert(result.colModel);
                jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid(
                                    {
                                        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, cell: "", id: "0" },
                                        url: "jqGridHandler.ashx",
                                        datatype: 'json',
                                        mtype: 'POST',

                                        data: colD,
                                        ColNames: colN,
                                        ColModel: ColM,
                                        height: "auto",
                                        gridview: true,
                                        Pager: '#UsersGrid',
                                        rowNum: 5,
                                        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                                        viewrecords: true,
                                        loadComplete: function (data) {
                                            alert('loaded completely');
                                        },
                                        loadError: function () {
                                            alert('error');
                                        }
                                    });
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert(x.readyState + ' ' + x.status + e.msg);
            }
        });

    });
```

Updated vesion for dynamic one

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace jqGridInWebForm {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for jqGridHandler
    /// </summary>
    public struct JQGridResults {
        public int page;
        public int total;
        public int records;
        public JQGridRow[] rows;
    }
    public struct JQGridRow {
        public int id;
        public string[] cell;
    }
    public enum GridType
    {
        GRID_TYPE_TEXT,
        GRID_TYPE_DATE,
        GRID_TYPE_INT,
        GRID_TYPE_DOUBLE
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class User {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

    }

    public class clsGridData
    {
        public List<string> _Columns = new List<string>();
        public List<string[]> _Cells = new List<string[]>();

        public void InitFields(string P_SQL, string P_TYPE)
        { 
            int _count;
            string connectionString = "";//P_SQL
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select * from tblusers";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // StoredProcedure;
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        string MyField;
                        for (_count = 0; _count < dataReader.FieldCount; _count++)
                        {
                            MyField = dataReader.GetName(_count);
                            _Columns.Add(MyField);
                        }

                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            string[] MyCell = new string[dataReader.FieldCount];
                            for (_count = 0; _count < dataReader.FieldCount; _count++)
                            {
                                MyCell[_count] = Convert.ToString(dataReader[_count]);                                
                            }
                            _Cells.Add(MyCell);
                        }
                    }

                }


            }

        }
    }



    /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for jqgridhandler
        /// </summary>
        public class jqGridHandler: IHttpHandler 
        {



            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
                HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                HttpResponse response = context.Response;


                string _search = request["_search"];
                string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
                string pageIndex = request["page"];
                string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
                string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];

                //int totalRecords;
                //List<User> users = GetUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
                clsGridData i_grid_data = new clsGridData();
                i_grid_data.InitFields("","");
                string output = BuildJQGridResults(i_grid_data, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex));
                //string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
                response.Write (output);
            }

            private string BuildJQGridResults(clsGridData P_GRID_DATA, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex)
            {

                JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
                List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
                int _count;

                foreach (String[] Cells in P_GRID_DATA._Cells)
                {
                    JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
                    row.cell = new string[Cells.GetUpperBound(0)];
                    //row.id = user.UserID;
                    for (_count = 0;_count< Cells.GetUpperBound(0); _count++)
                    {                        
                        row.cell[_count] = Cells[_count].ToString();
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }

                result.rows = rows.ToArray();
                result.page = pageIndex;
                result.total = (P_GRID_DATA._Cells.Count + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
                result.records = P_GRID_DATA._Cells.Count;
                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            }
            //private string BuildJQGridResults(List<User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords) {

            //    JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults ();
            //    List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow> ();
            //    foreach (User user in users) 
            //    {
            //        JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow ();
            //        row.id = user.UserID;
            //        row.cell = new string[6];

            //        row.cell[0] = user.UserID.ToString ();
            //        row.cell[1] = user.UserName;
            //        row.cell[2] = user.FirstName;
            //        row.cell[3] = user.MiddleName;
            //        row.cell[4] = user.LastName;
            //        row.cell[5] = user.EmailID;
            //        row.cell[6] = user.Phone ;



            //        rows.Add (row);
            //    }
            //    result.rows = rows.ToArray ();
            //    result.page = pageIndex;
            //    result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
            //    result.records = totalRecords;
            //    return new JavaScriptSerializer ().Serialize (result);
            //}




            private List<User> GetDummyUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords) 
            {
                var data = new List<User> 
                {
                    new User(){EmailID = "test@microsoft.com", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Araya", UserID = 1, UserName = "Efrem"}
                };
                totalRecords = data.Count;
                return data;
            }


        private List<User> GetUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords) 
        {
                List<User> users = new List<User> ();

                string connectionString = "";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (connectionString)) 
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ()) 
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandText = "select * from tblusers";
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // StoredProcedure;

                        //SqlParameter paramPageIndex = new SqlParameter ("@PageIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
                        //paramPageIndex.Value = Convert.ToInt32 (pageIndex);
                        //command.Parameters.Add (paramPageIndex);

                        //SqlParameter paramColumnName = new SqlParameter ("@SortColumnName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                        //paramColumnName.Value = sortColumnName;
                        //command.Parameters.Add (paramColumnName);

                        //SqlParameter paramSortorderBy = new SqlParameter ("@SortOrderBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
                        //paramSortorderBy.Value = sortOrderBy;
                        //command.Parameters.Add (paramSortorderBy);

                        //SqlParameter paramNumberOfRows = new SqlParameter ("@NumberOfRows", SqlDbType.Int);
                        //paramNumberOfRows.Value = Convert.ToInt32 (numberOfRows);
                        //command.Parameters.Add (paramNumberOfRows);

                        //SqlParameter paramTotalRecords = new SqlParameter ("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.Int);
                        //totalRecords = 0;
                        //paramTotalRecords.Value = totalRecords;
                        //paramTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        //command.Parameters.Add (paramTotalRecords);


                        connection.Open ();

                        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader ()) 
                        {
                            User user;
                            while (dataReader.Read ()) 
                            {
                                user = new User ();
                                user.UserID = (int)dataReader["UserID"];
                                user.UserName = Convert.ToString (dataReader["UserName"]);
                                user.FirstName = Convert.ToString (dataReader["FirstName"]);
                                user.MiddleName = Convert.ToString (dataReader["MiddleName"]);
                                user.LastName = Convert.ToString (dataReader["LastName"]);
                                user.EmailID = Convert.ToString (dataReader["EmailID"]);
                                users.Add (user);
                            }
                        }
                        //totalRecords = (int)paramTotalRecords.Value;
                    }
                    totalRecords = 0;
                    return users;
                }

            }
            public bool IsReusable {
                // To enable pooling, return true here.
                // This keeps the handler in memory.
                get { return false; }
            }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the source, now records are displayed very smoothly but the only problem is that the search is not working, can you please have a look?  My Codes are given below:

The aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="JQGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="JQGrid" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />--%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href="jqScripts/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqScripts/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqScripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 250,
                colNames: ['CustomerID', 'CompanyName', 'ContactName', 'ContactTitle', 'Address', 'City', 'PostalCode', 'Country'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'CustomerID', index: 'CustomerID', width: 75, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'CompanyName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'ContactName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'ContactTitle', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'Address', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'City', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'PostalCode', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'Country', width: 150, sortable: true }
                    ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#UsersGridPager',
                sortname: 'CustomerID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                caption: 'My Data'
            });

            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
    <table id="UsersGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <div id="UsersGridPager">
        </div>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="jqGridHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class jqGridHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        string _search = request["_search"];
        string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
        //string numberOfRows = "10";
        string pageIndex= request["page"];
        string sortColumnName= request["sidx"];
        string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];


        int totalRecords;
        //public DataTable GetDataTable(string sidx, string sord, int page, int pageSize)
        Collection<User> users = GetUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy, out totalRecords, _search);
        string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows), Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
        response.Write(output);
    }

    private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection<User> users,int numberOfRows, int pageIndex,int totalRecords)
    {

        JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
        List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
            row.id = user.CustomerID;
            row.cell = new string[8];
            row.cell[0] = user.CustomerID;
            row.cell[1] = user.CompanyName;
            row.cell[2] = user.ContactName;
            row.cell[3] = user.ContactTitle;
            row.cell[4] = user.Address;
            row.cell[5] = user.City;
            row.cell[6] = user.PostalCode;
            row.cell[7] = user.Country;

            rows.Add(row);
        }
        result.rows = rows.ToArray();
        result.page = pageIndex;
        result.total = totalRecords / numberOfRows;
        result.records = totalRecords;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
    }

    private Collection<User> GetUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords, string _search)
    {
        Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=ritetechno\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
        //<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=Abdul-THINK;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                int numRows=Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows)*(Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex));
                int excluderows=Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows)*((Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex)-1));
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP " + numRows + " CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, PostalCode, Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT TOP " + excluderows +" CustomerID FROM Customers)";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    User user;
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        user = new User();
                        user.CustomerID = Convert.ToString(dataReader["CustomerID"]);
                        user.CompanyName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["CompanyName"]);
                        user.ContactName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ContactName"]);
                        user.ContactTitle = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ContactTitle"]);
                        user.Address = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Address"]);
                        user.City = Convert.ToString(dataReader["City"]);
                        user.PostalCode = Convert.ToString(dataReader["PostalCode"]);
                        user.Country = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Country"]);
                        users.Add(user);                        
                    } 
                }
                string cmdTotRec = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers";
                SqlCommand chkTotRec = new SqlCommand(cmdTotRec, connection);
                totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(chkTotRec.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                connection.Close();
            }

            return users;
        }

    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }

    public struct JQGridResults
    {
        public int page;
        public int total;
        public int records;
        public JQGridRow[] rows;

    }
    public struct JQGridRow
    {
        public string id;
        public string[] cell;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is that you defined class `jqGridHandler` (`public class jqGridHandler : IHttpHandler`) **inside of** the `User` class. You should define it on the top level.

I don't comment the code of `GetUsers` included `string connectionString = ""` for example. You should know how you access your database.

Another minor error is the line

```
result.total = totalRecords / numberOfRows;
```

which should be fixed to

```
 result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / numberOfRows;
```

It is not so important, but I would prefer to use `List<User>` instead of `Collection<User>`.

After the changes the code will work (you can download from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm.zip) the demo project which I used). I recommend you additionally implement `loadError` event handle. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. When I tried my the modified version, then it did not display the data. I tried copy the the content of the file to my original file, then the same result. No data.  I tried the package under from download. It worked well. But there one difference, no CSS in my application and j<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="jqGridInWebForm.Sample" %>. My case <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample.WebForm1" %>. Is that make a difference???

Comment: @Efrem: do you tried to include `GetDummyUsers` instead of `GetUsers` in your code? Do you tried to include any `loadError`? Try to use at least `loadError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); }`. About your question with `codeBase`: I can't answer because I don't know all files from the project. I suggest that you modify my working demo step by step to yours. Then on one step you will find the error which you do.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt reply. 
As you said I modify your demo version  to my project. Now when I tried to connect to the database, it gave me an error totalRecords =(int)paramTotalRecords.Value; It gave me an error specific cast is not valid. I changed to totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(paramTotalRecords.Value); line, then the error is Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other type. What is the reason?? Thank you sir

Comment: @Efrem: I don't quite understand your DB-relative code. You don't post definition of the `tblusers` table. I don't see any parameters in your `command.CommandText`. It is just `"select * from tblusers"`. I see no sense to add many `Parameters` to the command. If I add parameters I add **always** types and length of the parameters. I use **never** `"select * from ..."`. I use named columns: `select UserID, UserName, ...`. In the `dataReader.Read()` loop I would never use `Convert.ToString` and use `GetInt32`, or `GetString` and so on. In my opinion the code is too dirty to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are absolutely right. I was modified the sql statement from stored procedure. If I change the command.commandtext= SPname and Command.commandType= commandType.StoredProcedure, then it will work as a parameter issue. Thank you for pointing me to this issue. 
The next step is I want to pull the column name dynamically to display on a grid. The procedure I am planning is to create a class and properties  dynamically with the given table and read the data using datareader. What is the best way to implement such issue?

Comment: @Efrem: Better is not to use dynamical grids and create one grid per one dataset. If you do decide to create grid dynamically you will have to load `colModel`, `colNames` and probably some other parameters from the database. You will have problem to manage the information. So my advice to stay on "static" grids.

Comment: I modified the code which has on updated version section on code page (server side). I tried to collect all the fileds from database. The result is coming. However, the result from JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize (result) is a string (not a json data). So the grid does not disply itself. 
Would you please help me in this reagrd? Thank you

Comment: @Efrem: Please read carefully [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to use the stackoverflow in correct way.

Comment: Sorry. I read the FAQ and the possible notifications due to not following the rules.

Comment: @Efrem: It's not so easy to manage `colModel` on the server side. In my opinion you should first get clear and good working code for *one grid* and only after then consider to manage `colModel` on the server. In many cases editing the file with the JavaScript which defines jqGrid is easier as editing of the corresponding information in the database. By the way you can't use `data: colD` if you use `datatype: 'json'`. In the case you have to use `datatype: 'local'` with some disadvantages in case of large size of data.

Comment: Thank you sir. Using uploaded VS package, I was able to run the application with static data/column.

Comment: @Efrem: your new code have many errors in the code. The parameters `ColNames`, `ColModel`, `Pager` will be ignored because there are written in the wrong case - JavaScript is case sensitive. Another parameter `data: colD` will be just ignored because you use `datatype: 'json'`. One more remark: if you format the code of the question you should select the code and click "{}" button. It will insert 4 blanks in every row of the selected code and all will be correct formatted. You current code will be wrong formatted because of missing blanks at the beginning of the lines with the code.

Comment: In the code, it said undefine colD=JQResult.colData line when I run the program. The problem is there is no reference from the jqgridhandler. When I modified the code to have such reference, the data appears during debugging process but not display a grid and data. What I guess, it is not serialize since on watch list using VS C# environment, it becomes string type. Should be the type string or JSON type?

Comment: @Efrem: You never defined variables `colD` and `colN` and `ColM` which you used in the jqGrid definition. You should use "var " before assignment of `colD` and `colN` and replace `ColM` to `colM`.

Comment: @Efrem: I recommend you always verify your code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). If you would use `/*jslint devel: true, browser: true, sloppy: true, vars: true, white: true */` options at the beginning of your code you will have less warnings and will see real errors. Later you can consider to write more strict JavaScript code and use another JSLint options.

Comment: I tested the code and got three errors which are undefined for variables. I defined the variables colD and colN. However, colM is defined before. Still no grid. Still I guess the reference for such variables should come from server. Do you have any suggestion to disply the grid? Thank you so much sir

Comment: @Efrem: I wrote you before that the variables names in JavaScript are **case sensitive**. You defined variable `colM` (see `var colM = JQResult.colModel;`), but used `ColM` (see `ColModel: ColM,` where there are one more error: `ColModel` must be `colModel`). The variables `colD` and `colN` are undefined like I wrote you in the previous comment. You should change `colD = JQResult.colData;` to `var colD = JQResult.colData;` and `colN = JQResult.colNames;` to `var colN = JQResult.colNames;` or just use `JQResult.colData` and `JQResult.colNames` directly.